# Object Detection model stuck at low mAP

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to reproduce the results of the SSDLite model reported in the MobileNetV2 paper (arXiv:1801.04381), which should achieve about 22.1% mAP on the COCO detection challenge. However, I am stuck at 9% mAP. This is strange behavior because the model does work somewhat, but is still far off from the reported result. Can this much of a gap be caused by hyperparameters/optimizer choices (I am using adam instead of sgd), or is it almost certain that there is a bug in my implementation?

It is also worth mentioning that the model successfully overfits a small subset of the training set, but on the whole training set the loss seems to reach a plateau fairly quickly.

Has anyone encountered a problem similar to this?

Comment: To reproduce results you have to use the same hyperparameters, including the optimizer and any learning rate schedule.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this much of a gap be caused by hyperparameters/optimizer choices
>   (I am using adam instead of sgd), or is it almost certain that there
>   is a bug in my implementation?

Even small changes in the hyperparameters and a different optimizer choice can impact the training and the resulting precision of the classifier a lot. So your low precision might not necessary be due to a bug but could also be due to wrong parametrization.

> It is also worth mentioning that the model successfully overfits a
>   small subset of the training set, but on the whole training set the
>   loss seems to reach a plateau fairly quickly.

Seems like you run into a local optimum which only works for a subset of your data, which could also be a pointer for an suboptimal parameterization.

Like @Matias Valdenegro also mentioned, to reproduce the exact result you might have to use the same parameters as in the original implementation.